# iText : how to refactor code to avoid multiple addCell in method

Tags: java, itext

I'm currently using iText for .pdf generation. One of my methods creates, formats and adds cells to a Table object but there are a number of cells(20-30) for this particular table, and the method itself has grown considerably.

The structure of the method is as follows:

```
/*create cells*/
Cell c1 = new Cell(new Paragraph("text1", textFont));
//...and so on for 20+ cells

/*format cell with custom method formatCell()*/
formatCell(c1, false);
//...and so on for 20+ cells

/*add cells to table object*/
table1.addCell(c1);
//...and so on again for 20+ cells
```

Is there a way where i could add the cells to the table without a stream of addCell statements?

EDIT: What I should've mentioned(apologies) is that formatCell will take a boolean parameter that will change on a per cell basis

Comment: use a list or an array?

Comment: Do you even need to access them later? If not, why even put them in a list? Just put a loop for `20+` iterations, and inside the loop body create a cell, format it, and add it to the table. This assumes the creation, formatting, and adding to the table can all happen at once for each cell, rather than needing to do each step to all cells at the same time as you are doing now.

Comment: Based on your edit, you're going to need to add details (or adapt a solution already given on your own) on how you determine what values to pass for creating `Paragraph`s and for `formatCell`'s boolean, assuming they're all potentially different for different cells.

Comment: @ajp15243 The creation parameters will change on a per cell basis, so each cells paragraph will contain different data to other cells and the font will change as well, there will be no pattern to this, as some cells are label cells, some will be "value" cells etc. This also applies to the formatCell method, as not every cell will have a false value.

Comment: @jbailie1991 To me, it sounds like you need to do some more thinking on the design of this, since you need to have some way to determine these different arguments for different types of cells. That kind of question (about program design) isn't entirely appropriate for SO, but should fit fine on https://programmers.stackexchange.com/ (that site deals with programming concepts and designs, while SO deals more with implementations).

Comment: @ajp15243 I'm afraid you may be right. Considering the randomness of the formatting and creation elements, it may be a case that there is no pattern to it, and I'll have to live with what I have

Comment: @jbailie1991 If you can generate or hardcode that information beforehand, in a list or map or array, then you could just pass that in to the code you're asking about specifically here. This is essentially what Xavier's second code block is doing (note the `String... texts` parameter).

Answer (score 1):

you could add your Cell to an `ArrayList`, and then iterate throught the `List`.

For example:

```
List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
cells.add(new Cell(new Paragraph("text1", textFont)));
//...and so on for 20+ cells

for(Cell cell:cells){
    formatCell(cell, false);
    table1.addCell(cell);
}
```

And to create your list of cells, you could create a method like this

```
private static List<Cell> createCells(Font textFont, String... texts){
    List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
    for(String text: texts){
        cells.add(new Cell(new Paragraph(text, textFont)));
    }
}
```

Comment: would that not result in 20-30 lines of ArrayList.add(cell)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
final List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<>();
/*create cells*/
cells.add(/* c1 */ new Cell(new Paragraph("text1", textFont)));
//...and so on for 20+ cells

/*format cell with custom method formatCell()*/
for (final Cell cell : cells) {
    formatCell(cell, false);
}

/*add cells to table object (or use the previous loop if nothing inbetween) */
for (final Cell cell : cells) {
    table1.addCell(cell);
}
```